# draw.io: How export a diagram as a figure but including a custom watermark?

Tags: diagrams, drawing

About the [draw.io](https://drawio-app.com) tool

Is there a way to export the diagram to any figure format **but** giving the option to include a custom watermark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it natively. There was an issue opened for it - [Add a watermark to the drawing output](https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/issues/1551), but it was closed without answers from the developers.

Comment: And I just created a new issue ... Do you know about a tool to let me add watermark to an existing figure?

Comment: @ManuelJordan You may try https://www.iloveimg.com/watermark-image